# how to use existing github yml files for Azure devops pipelines

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I want to create Azure DevOps pipelines, but instead of writing new yaml files, use prepared ones that are in a github repository.
I have connected GitHub to my Azure DevOps account, but I Can't see an option to use yaml files in that repository.
I only have an option to create a new pipeline yaml, and then set it in the repo folder structure.
If I try and set it on the location of the yaml file I want to use, which is already in the repo, I get - of course, an error stating there's a file there.
My work around is to set a new yaml file with a different name, copy the content from the existing file and then delete that one and rename the new file to the name of the file I copied from.

Surely there must be a better, easier, more logical and short way.
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Under project settings you should link your Github account.

[image]

Then you can go and create a new pipeline and select the Github location

[image]

after this step, your available github repositories will appear and you can select your existing .YML file.

[image]

Existing pipeline:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much GeralexGR. However this does not work for me. When I try doing it your way, I do not get the table you showed, and when i press the "Connect your GitHub account" button, I get an empty list with an error "You've already added all the repositories you have permission to. Not seeing the repository you want to add? Double-check your repository permissions, then try again. So I don't have the "Existing Azure Pipelines YAML file". Also, when i try to create new Pipeline, I go straight to the creation page, linked directly to the GitHub repository root folder.